# How do keys work in min and max?

Tags: python, key, max, min

I run through the following sequence of statements:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> min(a, key=lambda x: x < 5.3)
6
>>> max(a, key=lambda x: x < 5.3)
0
```

The min and max give the exact opposite of what I was expecting.

The python documentation on min and max is pretty sketchy.

Can anyone explain to me how the "key" works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation of the `key` argument

Key works like this:

```
a_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'canary', 'doll', 'elephant']

min(a_list, key=len)
```

returns `'doll'`, and

```
max(a_list, key=len)
```

returns `'elephant'`

You provide it with a function, and it uses the minimum or maximum of the results of the function applied to each item to determine which item to return in the result.

### Application

If your function returns a boolean, like yours, for min it'll return the first of the minimum of True or False, (which is False) which would be 6 or the first of the max (True) which would be 0.

To see this:

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dict((i, i<5.3) for i in a))
{0: True,
 1: True,
 2: True,
 3: True,
 4: True,
 5: True,
 6: False,
 7: False,
 8: False,
 9: False}
```

Why?

```
>>> min([True, False])
False
>>> max([True, False])
True
```

### Explanation

Why is `True` greater than `False`?

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

It turns out that `True` and `False` are very closely related to `1` and `0`. They even evaluate the same respectively.

Comment: JB and Aaron: wish I could accept both your answers.  Will give it to Aaron since he typed more.  :)  Thanks!  Now I get it.  I was interpreting "key" as a "filter" when they are instead the way that the elements should be compared.

Answer (score 4):

because all values are either `True` or `False`. So the first one of each is chosen.

```
min([True, 1, False, 0])
```

will return `False` instead of `0` because both have the same value but `False` happens first

Your code uses a `key` function with only boolean values so, for `min`, the first `False`
happens at the number `6`.  So it is the chosen one.

What you probably want to do is:

```
min(x for x in range(10) if x < 5.3)
```